# Windows 10 share menu

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10, there's a share option within an app(Xodo pdf viewer)
When I try to use it, I see that only certain apps appear on this sharing menu such as mail, one-note etc. I think this sharing menu is controlled by windows 10. Would it be possible to add other apps to this sharing menu somehow, such as a dictionary or a translator app? ( so I could share unknown words to those apps withing pdf reader to check their meanings? )

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why do you believe this is a function of the OS and not the application? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: The Metro Windows 10 sharing panel I'm familiar with has a rather prominently placed message to visit the Windows Store to add items to it. If you're speaking of this panel, have you followed the directions on it?

Comment: I added a screenshot. There is no such setting in the app itself, and the menu more looked like a windows populated list to me? Even though I'm not sure.

Comment: Yea, that's the Windows share menu. At the bottom of that menu should be a link to the Microsoft Store, and in the store you should be able to find dictionary and translation apps.

Comment: Yes, and I tried adding dictionary and translation apps from Microsoft store however those still don't show up in this menu. Even Microsoft's own translator. I'm not trying to make it translate a whole document by the way. Still would use it as a dictionary if it worked. To translate single unknown words. By the way, I also sent an email to the app developer asking this however I doubt that I will get a response.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted below. In short, the Share menu MAY only support sharing the entire document. A more common UI method for performing an action on a single word or an arbitrary selection is to place those actions in the right-click contextual menu.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to add other apps to this sharing menu somehow, such as a dictionary or a translator app?

You would have to contact the developer of [Xodo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xodo-pdf-reader-editor/9wzdncrdjxp4#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) to determine that.

> In Windows 10, there's a share option within an app(Xodo pdf viewer.

It is a feature of the application, not Windows 10, the application also runs on Windows 8.1.

> the menu more looked like a windows populated list to me?

You have provided a screenshot of a UWP application.

> When I try to use it, I see that only certain apps appear on this sharing menu such as mail, one-note etc.

The majority of applications, in the screenshot, offer a framework to implement something like this.  A translator application or a dictionary application does not normally have a social networking framework.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Ramhound posted earlier:

It depends on a lot of things.

Apps have to use the APIs provided by Microsoft in order to show in the Share menu, and you'd have to determine whether you could "share" single words. In a PDF viewer, this would mean the application would have to be able to recognize single words in order to send them to a dictionary. Many PDFs include text information, but many others (especially those scanned optically) are actually pictures and you have to run additional tools called OCR (Optical Character Recognition) in order to handle this.

And, in the Windows 10 Share UI, you'd have to highlight the desired text and then click the share button, when it is more common to highlight the text and then right-click and choose tools or options to run against your selected text.

**So, to answer your question:**

1. Yes, it should be possible to add items to the Share menu and you'll find those apps in the Microsoft Store, including dictionaries and translation tools.
2. No, it does not make sense within current normal UI design to open a Share menu to run selected text against a dictionary or translator, though that does not mean it could not be done.
3. The application would have to support this function. So even adding dictionaries and translators to the generic Share menu would not be enough if the application did not yet already have facilities to support this.